# Can RSA encrypt infinitely many messages?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In RSA encryption, a message $m$ encrypted using a public key $(n,e)$ and decrypted by private key $d$, according to following relation (where $c$ is encrypted data);

$c = m ^ e (\mod n)$

$m = c^d (\mod n)$

Am I correct to think that encrypted value can have $n$ distinct values (because of $(\mod n)$), and therefore, only $n$ different messages can be encrypted/decrypted without loss of information?

Comment: Right. In practice, the value of $n$ was rather high, say $10^{200}$. But RSA is no longer used by the NSA.

Comment: I suppose you can also split longer messages in chunks shorter than $n$

Comment: Indeed, if $m>n$, then you split $m$ up into pieces, each less than $n$, and encode (and decode) one piece at a time.